# Java-Execute bat file when clicking button, before closing the Java window

Tags: java, batch-file

I have a button, what I want is to click the button to execute a bat file background, which will generate a file in a folder, and the Java window remains there.

But in my code, I need to close the Java window to get the bat file executed.

Would you please help to check where I need to change?

I don't need to see the bat screen. Thanks!

```
final JButton importMap = new JButton("Import");

    importMap.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg1) {

            //String osm = osmFile_path.replaceAll("\\","\\\\");
            System.out.println("You are going to import:"+osmFile_path);
            //Runtime.getRuntime().exec()
            try {
                FileWriter fw2 = new FileWriter("C:\\SUMO\\bin\\OSMTEST.bat");
                fw2.write("@echo off");
                fw2.write("\r\n");
                fw2.write("cmd");
                fw2.write("\r\n");
                fw2.write("set default_dir=C:\\SUMO\\bin");
                fw2.write("\r\n");
                fw2.write("start /b C:\\SUMO\\bin\\netconvert --osm-files="+osmFile_path+" --output-file="+osmnet_file);
                fw2.close();
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C start /b C:\\SUMO\\bin\\OSMTEST.bat");
            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    content.add(importMap);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the following code indeed:

```
    try {
    FileWriter fw2 = new FileWriter("C:\\SUMO\\bin\\OSMTEST.bat");
    fw2.write("@echo off");
    fw2.write("\r\n");
    //fw2.write("cmd");//No need to specify this line
    fw2.write("\r\n");
    fw2.write("set default_dir=C:\\SUMO\\bin");
    fw2.write("\r\n");
    fw2.write("start /b C:\\SUMO\\bin\\netconvert --osm-files="+osmFile_path+" --output-file="+osmnet_file);
    fw2.write("\r\n");
    fw2.write("Exit");//To close bat file
    fw2.write("\r\n");
    fw2.close();
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + "C:\\SUMO\\bin\\OSMTEST.bat");//use the protoclhandler
    process.waitFor();//Waits the process to terminate
    if (process.exitValue() == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Process Executed Successfully");
    }
} catch(Exception e) {//Process.waitFor() can throw InterruptedException
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your codes works well exception one little thing. It says here was an error for
    process.waitFor();
And I removed it then it's ok.  Do you know why?

Comment: @JiayiGuo  I am glad. :) . What is that exceptional case?

Comment: @JiayiGuo: Process.waitFor() throws `InterruptedException` . If you have not caught that then it would lead to compile time error. That's why I changed the caught exception in your code to `Exception`..!! This statement is very useful to analyze if the process is executed successfully or not so it is MHO to include those lines in your code..

Comment: Thanks! I didn't notice the difference for "Exception".I added exception catch then it passed. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the `start` argument in the `Runtime.getRuntime.exec()` parameters. It causes to open a new window for executing the specified command.

This should work

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C C:\\SUMO\\bin\\OSMTEST.bat");`